# Jquery toggle Left to right animation

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I have created a jquery toggle animation but for some reason it isn't working.

Can Anyone be of assistance?

Please see updated fiddle. 
class="search-container-wrap" is meant to slide out from left to right

http://jsfiddle.net/VdWFm/

```
        /*  SHOWS CHART SEARCH
    ===================================================================*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-charts-go').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.search-container-wrap').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 500);
    $(this).next('.search-container-wrap').stop().show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 500);
   });
});
```

Thanks a bunch !!!!

Comment: You didn't include jQuery and jQuery UI library in your Fiddle ;)

Comment: What exactly should it be doing? I just see a gray square. Where do you think it goes wrong? What did you try to fix it?

Comment: I included libraries in Fiddle but now just flashing div aside gray sqare...

Comment: Please see updated fiddle. <div class="search-container-wrap is meant to slide out from left to right http://jsfiddle.net/VdWFm/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery conflicting code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920025/jquery-conflicting-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in `$(this).next('.search-container-wrap')` since the anchor being clicked doesn't have such a sibling. Try `$('.search-container-wrap')` instead as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ez3MQ/10/).

I took the liberty of making it slide in and out as well.

Comment: Can I not use jquery jquery-1.10.1.min.js? or do I need another?

Comment: When you want to use jquery 1.10.1 you will have to upgrade jquery ui also. Check [the jquery ui upgrade guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/). Sadly jsFiddle doesn't support jqueryui 1.10 yet.