# Jquery conflicting code

Tags: jquery

The last part of my jquery code does not work when i place it with all the code here. on its one it works.  I believe the issue is because a jquery conflication.  does anyone know how to overcome this is issue? The last part of jquery is an animation toggle

Please see demo http://jsfiddle.net/uyWNH/1/

```
        /*  charts TABS (WORKING)
    ===================================================================*/

    $(".chart-tabs a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        idTab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".chart-tabs .active").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(idTab).siblings().stop().fadeOut(100, function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(idTab).fadeIn(100);
            }, 100)
        })
        // $(idTab).show().siblings().hide();
    })


        /*  SEARCH GENDER (WORKING)
    ===================================================================*/

       $().ready(function(){

        $(".inp-radio").iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
            radioClass: 'iradio_square-green'
        });

        $(".wrap-icon-ratio").click(function(){
           $(this).find("ins").click();
        })

        $(".wrap-icon-ratio ins").click(function(){
            $(".wrap-icon-ratio.active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("active");
        });

    })

       /*   FOLLOW POP UP (WORKING)
===================================================================*/
$('.social-popup-btn').hover(function()
{
     if($('.social-name-popup').is(':visible'))
        $('.social-name-popup').fadeOut(750 /* Animation Time */, function()
     {
        // animation complete callback
         $('#cat').fadeIn(750);
     });
}, function()
{
     // Mouse Leave callback
});


        /*  SHOWS CHART SEARCH (NOT WORKING)
    ===================================================================*/
$(function(){
    $('.search-charts-go').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($('.search-container-wrap').hasClass('visible')) {
        $('.search-container-wrap').stop().animate({
            'width' : '0'
        }, 1000, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('visible')
        });
    } else {
        $('.search-container-wrap').addClass('visible').stop().animate({
            'width' : '400'
        }, 1000);
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working? whether the click handler is getting called?

Comment: also can you share the relevant markup also

Comment: Please see demo http://jsfiddle.net/uyWNH/1/

Comment: any error in your console?

Comment: there is an error saying `iCheck` is not a function, if you remove it something is happening, it this ok http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bzLFv/1/

Comment: you need to add the script [http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/](http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/) to use .iCheck

Comment: the fiddle works but when i add it to my document it still doesnt :s ?

Comment: It appears that two of your previous questions contain the same code as this question: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914019/jquery-toggle-not-sliding) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912911/jquery-toggle-left-to-right-animation).

Comment: Yes, thats correct, the problem accrued when adding the jquery to a document with other jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't need to repeat

```
$(function(){
});
```

use this for the non working part:

```
       /*  SHOWS CHART SEARCH
    ===================================================================*/
    $('.search-charts-go').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($('.search-container-wrap').hasClass('visible')) {
        $('.search-container-wrap').stop().animate({
            'width' : '0'
        }, 1000, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('visible')
        });
    } else {
        $('.search-container-wrap').addClass('visible').stop().animate({
            'width' : '400'
        }, 1000);
    }
   });
```

Comment: Please see demo jsfiddle.net/uyWNH/1

Comment: remove the .iCheck call and all works... http://jsfiddle.net/uyWNH/1/